# Recognizing the decibel level of an audio segment

Tags: c#, c++, audio, microphone

I need to compare the decibel level of two audio segments. How can I determine the decibel level of an audio segment captured through the microphone, and compare it to a certain value, without recording the audio? I am looking for a C# or C++ solution.

Comment: Is this a school project? You realize nobody would spend few hours doing the research for you.. Google **Naudio**, this would do the trick for such a project, but make sure to show some effort next time.

Comment: Fixed typos and grammatical errors.